# How to do teshuva for making fun of a rabbinic explanation?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah

Does a non-Jew in the process of converting need to repent for making fun of a statement that was reportedly made by a Jewish sage (e.g. saying that 'no one with a mind can accept it')? If so, what do Jewish sources say regarding how to go about such repentance?

Comment: Interesting question. I would assume, that it wouldn't be as much of a problem for non Jews being that they weren't commanded to follow and listen to the sages.

Comment: @user613 maybe, but they are still holy men...

Comment: Right. It's still definitely a bad thing